# How to echo inside echo?

Tags: php, html

```
echo "<td>" .
     '<input type="checkbox" name="select[]" id="select"  onclick="checkAll(this)" 
      value ="<?php  echo  $pro ?>" >'. 
     "</td>";
```

I want to echo value in input by php.

Comment: Just `$pro` nothing else

Answer (score 11):

Use string concatenation:

```
echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="select[]" id="select" ' .
                'onclick="checkAll(this)" value ="' . $pro . '" ></td>';
```

**Alternatively**

You can just *put* the PHP variable inside the `echo`, and the value contained in it would be *printed*

```
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='select[]' id='select' 
      onclick='checkAll(this)' value ='$pro'></td>";
```

Its worth noting here that value inside `''` are parsed and if they contain a variable, then value of the variable is printed
Else if value is inside `""` then variable is printed as it is.

So, if you just interchange `""` with `''`, you'll avoid lot of concatenation mess! :)

**PHP :**(*note the swapped `'` with `"`*)

```
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='select[]' id='select' 
      onclick='checkAll(this)' value ='$pro'></td>";
```

**Output :** (*$pro = "abcd";*)

```
<td><input type='checkbox' name='select[]' id='select' 
    onclick='checkAll(this)' value ='abcd'></td>
```

Comment: I am stunned myself :)

Comment: @mudasobwa : gotta be your lucky day pal....honestly, i am craving to downvote you now!!! :D :p

Comment: Thanks @NoobEditor for entering the detailed explanation. If I could I would share 4 out of 8 votes with you :)

Comment: @mudasobwa : now worries fella.....its not about votes - *or may be some times* ! :D

Answer (score 3):

The previous answer is one way, although, I would advise to use inline php instead as it will be much more readable.

```
?><td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="select[]" id="select"  onclick="checkAll(this)" 
  value ="<?=$pro?>" /> 
 </td>
<?php
```

Answer (score 1):

you dont need to do that

use this

```
 echo"<td><input type='checkbox' name='select[]' id='select'  onclick='checkAll(this)' value ='".$pro."'/></td>";
```

Comment: Why use " if you use string concatenation ?

Comment: It would help if you explain what you did, rather than just do. Also, linking to specific documentation

Comment: **assume i did -1, you are just repeating answer!!**

Comment: When i was writing, there was no answer there..

" <-- doesn't matter, this is all about how you play with strings..
even this will work  value ='$pro'

Answer (score 0):

Its already a PHP block.. you need not open PHP again inside echo... Just give it like this...

```
echo "<td>" .
     '<input type="checkbox" name="select[]" id="select"  onclick="checkAll(this)" 
      value ="$pro" >'. 
     "</td>";
```