# I am not getting the $j value inside for loop in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, for-loop

I have a code like this:

```
for($j=1;$j<3;$j++)
{
    $output.='
        <span id="<?php echo "delete-".$j; ?>">
          <?php echo $j; ?>
            </span>
             ';
}
```

Inside for loop I am using the HTML code. And I am trying to access the $j value inside for loop using php 'echo()'. But I am not getting the $j value inside php tags.
How to get $j values inside php tags?

I need the output value like

```
<span id="delete-1">1</span>
<span id="delete-2">2</span>
<span id="delete-3">3</span>
```

Comment: If you can sort out how you use quotes, you don't need the `echo` as you can put the value directly into the output (along the lines of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27225213/how-to-echo-inside-echo/27225234)

Comment: Did you solve your issue?
If not just know that your code can be written as below,
`'<span id="delete-'.$j.'">'.$j.'</span>'` just as @NigelRen mentioned above

Comment: You cannot acccess variables in single quotes ''. Just use echo with "" double quotes and you can use variables as much as you like.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Issue got cleared.